# Apple Mach-0 linker error duplicate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

I have written a straight forward program, but getting duplicate symbol linker error (error below) There is nothing additional in the .h file excepting for the @interface Fraction : NSObject @end

I am rather new to xcode.

```
//SAMPLE CODE

#import "JTViewController.h"

@interface Fraction ()

-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;

@end

@implementation Fraction

{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

-(void) print
{
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator:(int)n
{
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator:(int)d
{
    denominator = d;
}

@end

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        // Create an instance of Fraction and initialise it

        Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        //Set Fraction to 1/3

           [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
            [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

            //Display the fraction using the print method

            [myFraction print];
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

This is the error

```
Ld /Users/jamesmurray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrandNew-akqlirretjwoeuaqkrwlbqmlqxlc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BrandNew.app/BrandNew normal i386
    cd /Users/jamesmurray/AppsDev/BrandNew
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/jamesmurray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrandNew-akqlirretjwoeuaqkrwlbqmlqxlc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jamesmurray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrandNew-akqlirretjwoeuaqkrwlbqmlqxlc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/jamesmurray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrandNew-akqlirretjwoeuaqkrwlbqmlqxlc/Build/Intermediates/BrandNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BrandNew.build/Objects-normal/i386/BrandNew.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/jamesmurray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrandNew-akqlirretjwoeuaqkrwlbqmlqxlc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BrandNew.app/BrandNew

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/jamesmurray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrandNew-akqlirretjwoeuaqkrwlbqmlqxlc/Build/Intermediates/BrandNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BrandNew.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
    /Users/jamesmurray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrandNew-akqlirretjwoeuaqkrwlbqmlqxlc/Build/Intermediates/BrandNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BrandNew.build/Objects-normal/i386/JTViewController.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea where it came from. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously there is another `main` function in the file with the implementation of the `JTViewController` class.

Comment: Just an update: when I change int main (int...) to int new name (int...) it builds. What is the significance of main causing the error?

Comment: you can only have 1 `main` function

Comment: You can only have globally visible non-common symbols (like non-static functions) defined once.

Comment: Thanks for the help Hristo Liev, I found the main duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Like the linker error says, you have two `main()` functions; one in `main.m` and one in `JTViewController.m`.

Remove the one in `JTViewController.m` (move the functionality into `main.m`).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about `main` here. You can only have one globally visible non-common symbol in your object files. Non-static functions are globally visible and non-common symbols, hence you can only have a function with a specific name defined only once. For example:

`a.c`:

```
int func() { ... }
```

`b.c`:

```
void func(int arg) { ... }
```

When both files are compiled, it creates two globally visible symbols with the name of `func` (with whatever decoration the compiler might apply to the symbol), despite the difference in the argument lists and the return types. As the linker tries to resolve all symbol references in order to produce the final executable, it faces the hard choice of selecting the right version of `func`, so it takes the most direct approach - simply gives you an error about duplicate symbol definition and bails out.

This is not a requirement unique to the C language (and Objective-C is basically a runtime extension of C) as it is imposed by the system linker. It also translates to many other languages like Objective-C, C++, Fortran, Pascal, etc. In C++ function symbols are decorated according to the namespace they live in and the list of their arguments (the former enables function overloading), but again one cannot have two functions with the same list of arguments in the same namespace defined in different source files.

Usually C and C++ functions are compiled to globally visible symbols unless the `static` modifier is applied:

`a.c`:

```
static int func() { ... }
```

`b.c`:

```
void func(int arg) { ... }
```

This would not result in a global symbol `func` in `a.o` clashing with the one in `b.o` and the linker would not complain. It would also work if rather `func` in `b.c` is given the `static` treatment or if both functions are `static`.